# pandas DataFrame dropped column appearing again

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry if I am doing something stupid, but I am very puzzled by this issue: I pass a DataFrame to a function, and inside that function I add a column and drop it. Nothing strange until here, but after the function has finished the DataFrame of the global namescope is showing the added&dropped column. If I declare the DF as global, this is not happening...

This test code is showing the issue in the four cases resulting from the combination of Python 3.3.3/2.7.6 and pandas 0.13.0/0.12.0:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pandas as pd

# FUNCTION DFcorr
def DFcorr(df):
    # Calculate column of accumulated elements
    df['SUM']=df.sum(axis=1)
    print('DFcorr: DataFrame after add column:')
    print(df)
    # Drop column of accumulated elements
    df=df.drop('SUM',axis=1)
    print('DFcorr: DataFrame after drop column:')
    print(df)  

# FUNCTION globalDFcorr
def globalDFcorr():
    global C
    # Calculate column of accumulated elements
    C['SUM']=C.sum(axis=1)
    print('globalDFcorr: DataFrame after add column:')
    print(C)
    # Drop column of accumulated elements
    print('globalDFcorr: DataFrame after drop column:')
    C=C.drop('SUM',axis=1)
    print(C)  

######################### MAIN #############################
C = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1, 2]), ('B', [3 ,4])], orient='index', columns['one', 'two'])
print('\nMAIN: Initial DataFrame:')
print(C)
DFcorr(C)
print('MAIN: DataFrame after call to DFcorr')
print(C)

C = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1, 2]), ('B', [3 ,4])], orient='index', columns=['one', 'two'])
print('\nMAIN: Initial DataFrame:')
print(C)
globalDFcorr()
print('MAIN: DataFrame after call to globalDFcorr')
print(C)
```

And here you are the output:

```
MAIN: Initial DataFrame:
   one  two
A    1    2
B    3    4

[2 rows x 2 columns]
DFcorr: DataFrame after add column:
   one  two  SUM
A    1    2    3
B    3    4    7

[2 rows x 3 columns]
DFcorr: DataFrame after drop column:
   one  two
A    1    2
B    3    4

[2 rows x 2 columns]
MAIN: DataFrame after call to DFcorr
   one  two  SUM
A    1    2    3
B    3    4    7

[2 rows x 3 columns]

MAIN: Initial DataFrame:
   one  two
A    1    2
B    3    4

[2 rows x 2 columns]
globalDFcorr: DataFrame after add column:
   one  two  SUM
A    1    2    3
B    3    4    7

[2 rows x 3 columns]
globalDFcorr: DataFrame after drop column:
   one  two
A    1    2
B    3    4

[2 rows x 2 columns]
MAIN: DataFrame after call to globalDFcorr
   one  two
A    1    2
B    3    4

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

What am I missing? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note this line in `DFCorr`:

```
df=df.drop('SUM',axis=1)
```

The `df.drop` method returns a new DataFrame. It does not mutate the original `df`.

Inside `DFcorr`, `df` is just a local variable. *Assignments* to `df` do not affect the global variable `C`. Only *mutations* of `df` would affect `C`.

So, you could make `DFcorr` behave more like `globalDFcorr` by changing that line to:

```
df.drop('SUM',axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Should then I understand that when using the DataFrame identifier in the function scope (`df`in this case) it could arbitrarily refer to the global variable or to the local one? I mean, from the answer, should I understand that in `df['SUM']=df.sum(axis=1)` the `df` is affecting the global variable while in `df=df.drop('SUM',axis=1)` and in `print(df)` the `df` is referring the local variable?

Comment: I let here my reasoning in order you could check if I have properly understood your answer: If I think in `df` as a C/C++ pointer, at the beginning of the called function it points to the DataFrame in the global scope (here `C`) and when doing `df['SUM']=df.sum(axis=1)` it is so referring to `C`, but when doing  `df=df.drop('SUM',axis=1)`, then, `df` becomes to point to a new DataFrame that is local to the function. Is this reasoning right? Many thanks.

Comment: @khyox: Yes, I think you have it! Here is a explanation of Python's [pass by assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8140747/190597) function calling paradigm.

Comment: Under the hood, Python translates `df['SUM'] = ...` into a call to  `df.__setitem__('SUM', ...)` which mutates `df`. Thus `df` keeps pointing to the same object that `C` points to. But `df = ...` reassigns `df` to point to a new object, so further mutation of `df` would no longer affect `C`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link and your explanation! Both succinct and clear.